# Validation of date using Javascript in cognos

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cognos, cognos-8

1. When the users select the To Period as < From Period then an error message should be thrown to select a period >= From Period
2. When the user selects more than 12 months then a warning message should be displayed as "The report will take more time to display the dashboard".

The from prompt and to prompt are drop down and the use value is integer (e.g. jan 2013 =1 ,feb 2013=2)

I need a Javascript to validate and display the error message on selection of the dates.
Before submitting the report.

Comment: Upgrade to 10.2 and take advantage of the [Prompt API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r2m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.0.doc/c_rs_nf_10_2_prmpt_api.html). A solution in any other version will not be cross-version compatible and could even break between browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to validate that the from date is before the to date.

I do not know if you are using plain JS or jQuery but for whichever you use retrieve the values from your inputs in the usual way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkDates() {
  var to = document.getElementsByName('to')[0].value;
  var from = document.getElementsByName('from')[0].value;

  if(to < from) {
    alert('To date must be after from date!');
  } 
}
</script>

<select name="from" onchange="checkDates()">
  <option value="1">JAN</option>
  <option value="2">FEB</option> 
  ...
</select>

<select name="to" onchange="checkDates()">
  <option value="1">JAN</option>
  <option value="2">FEB</option> 
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using javascript but as soon I have selected the value from drop down i have to get the alert, and the values used are month number as 1,2,3. where 1 is jan. its not working :( its allowing me to submit the wrong selection not getting the alert

Comment: It will be working if you define this as a function and you call it from the appropriate place. In your case, if you have a form, you will have to implement its submit event.

Comment: Updated the answer as per your comment. You could also do it as an onsubmit event shown by Lajos Arpad

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer, as I knew it is working if you put it inside a validational function. My previous comment was addressed to Raj.

Comment: I have got one java script it works fine , when I add a button from cognos and in the property of that button i have an URL where I have given this function "javascript:validate();" then it works fine,but I dont want to click or add any button.The script should automatically validate when the user clicks on the 'to date'.

Answer (score 0):

If we put eshortie's code into a validation function and we define the submit event of the form, then it should work. Example:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(){
        var validactionalResult = validation();
        if (validationalResult !== true) {
            alert(validationalResult);
        } else {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yoururl",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                    if (response === "success") {
                        //do something
                    } else {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                },
            error: function() {
                    alert("Unsuccessful connection attempt");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have got the java script it works fine , when I add a button from cognos and in the property of that button i have an URL where I have given this function "javascript:validate();" , but I dont want to click or add any button.The script should automatically validate when the user clicks on the 'to date'.

Comment: @Raj, in any case you need the function to validate. If you do not want to add a button and you want to click on the 'to date' (whatever that is in your case) then create a click event for the structural representation of the 'to date'. In fact I do not see what the problem is.